# Read vendor-specific BLE HID reports on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I have a project in which I have to read vendor-specific data from a custom BLE device in Android. However, everywhere I looked says that Android "absorbs" HID reports and has no access points for it either through JDK or NDK.

I even tried to create a "priv-app" application and get the BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission to enable notifications on every characteristic of service 1812, but with no luck (notifications are enabled, but I'm never notified of an event).

Is there any possible way of doing this without building a custom version of Android?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you figure out an answer to your problem?